# Can I move and redownload the preinstalled Wii U games?

Tags: wii-u, digital-distribution

The Wii U comes preloaded with a few games now (e.g., *Super Mario 3D World*, *Nintendo Land*).

1. If I delete them, can I get them back or re-download them?
2. Can I move them onto a USB drive and use them on another Wii U console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Provided you have created a Nintendo Network ID on the console, yes. The games are tied to your account on the console and you may redownload them at any time from the eShop. This will only work on the Wii U on which you created your NNID.
2. No, you can't move games to a different console. The only way to do anything like this would be the [Wii U System Transfer](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9159/p/431/c/266), but that transfers absolutely everything from one console to another.